# New Form is missing site columns when Content Type was updated with new site columns

Tags: content-type, form, edit-form

I have a calender with Event and Reservation Content Type. I went to both the content types and added 4 site columns (Inspection, Fuel Check, Wing Check and Log Check).

Now when I add a new item to the calendar the newform does not show these fields. However, new fields show up if I edit an existing entry or create a new entry and then do edit on it.

Is there a way to fix this without modifying the newform in spdesigner or infopath?

Comment: Seems like your New Form is not picking either of the Content Type by default, can you see other options in New Item drop-down?

Comment: Is there a powershell way to push the new columns (part of the content type) to the new form. I dont see any drop down to select a desire content type.

Comment: If you go to List settings, under content types how many and which content types do you see ?

Comment: I see both Event and Reservation and Even being number 1. but if i change it reservation the new form stays the same and doesnt show additional fields.

Comment: Can you go to the content types again and make sure you select the check-box at the bottom (which is something like push changes to lists that are using this content type)

Comment: I went to the Site Settings > Site Content Types > Clicked the Content Type "Event"> Clicked "Advanced Settings" > Made sure "Update all content types inheritering from this type" radio button is set to "Yes" > Clicked "OK". and Still nothing. Repeated same steps for "Reservation" CT